# Power calculations for moderator analyses in RCT

Tags: sample-size, experiment-design, statistical-power

I am running a randomised controlled trial of a savings intervention in India whereby randomisation is at the individual level (not clusters). In my power calculations, I also want to factor in a range of heterogeneity analyses that I want to conduct, looking at 5 different hypothesised effect size moderators (some binary and some continuous). Can anyone help me with how I can do the power analyses for these? I have found PowerUp! (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/19345747.2012.673143) to be super useful for cluster RCTs but my trial is individually powered and the program therefore not applicable. Any hint on an alternative software/program that I can use?